# Bluez 5.17 and beyond, Unable to register device interface

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to implement a BLE peripheral on my device that has a bluetooth HW. I am compiling Bluez 5.16 for this device with the options --enable-experimental and --enable-maintainer-mode. Everything seems to work fine with version 5.16, I can use an iPhone app (LightBlue) to see my peripheral. But as soon as I update to any version beyond 5.16, nothing seems to work and I get the error `Unable to register device interface for 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C`, as shown in the full stack at the bottom.

I looked at the code and it is when bluetoothd tries to dbus-register. Why whould dbus-register fail?

```
if (g_dbus_register_interface(dbus_conn,
        device->path, DEVICE_INTERFACE,
        device_methods, NULL,
        device_properties, device,
        device_free) == FALSE) {
    error("Unable to register device interface for %s", address);
            device_free(device);
            return NULL;
}
```

Error:

```
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 6B:6F:6B:E
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_create() dst 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C       
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() address 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C      
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() Creating device /org/bluez/hci0
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 d
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_create() dst 6B:6F:6B
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() address 6B:6F:6
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() Creating device
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:btd_device_set_temporary() t
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:btd_device_set_temporary() temporary 1      
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_connect_list_remove() device /org/b
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/attrib-server.c:connect_event()                      
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_create() dst 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() address 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C      
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() Creating device /org/bluez/hci0
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.err bluetoothd[222]: Unable to register device interface for 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_free() 0x8a009b0                     
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_connect_list_remove
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/attrib-server.c:connect_event()      
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_create() dst 6B:6F:6B
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() address 6B:6F:6
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_new() Creating device
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: Unable to register device interface for 6
Jul 22 20:52:48 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_free() 0x8a009b0
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 6B:6F:6B:E2:61:6C
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()                
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection() Removing tempor
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_remove() Removing device /org/bluez/h
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:btd_device_unref() Freeing device /org/bluez
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_free() 0x8a00108                     
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 6B:6
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.debug bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()                         
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 6
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Jul 22 20:52:52 daemon.info bluetoothd[222]: bluetoothd[222]: src/device.c:device_remove() Removing dev
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? It seems that the problem persist until now (bluez-5.23)